# Excel - SUBTOTAL but only where particular criteria is met (SUMIF/AVERAGEIF)

Tags: excel-formula, average, subtotal

EDIT: The document is set up like a series of dashboards. Some if the data linked to the many graphs is in pivot tables and some just regular tables. Because there are so many graphs, I use some user selection buttons and fields to change what data is shown in these graphs.
Some users open the file in office 2016.
All solutions I found were either limited to 365 or involved creating new data tables or columns which I was trying to avoid as it would mean a fair bit of rework. I instead just used a set of nested IFS and will eventually look at changing these particular pivots to regular tables with index lookups to enable the actual data to be in multiple columns.

I currently use a SUBTOTAL function to either sum, count or average a bunch of cells in a range. I was previously manually filtering the range so I was only totaling the rows I wanted, however the need has arisen to be able to look at several criteria at once.
i.e in the example below, I was previously manually filtering range to only include "Apple" but now I need to be able to total "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" separately, at the same time.

The subtotal fields are used in graphs and I have a cell (F5) that houses a number corresponding to either SUM, COUNT or Average (9, 2 or 1) to use in the subtotal formulas in the "Summary table" which is linked to other functionality within the workbook and I need to still be able to retain that functionality.

Example of how my sheet is setup:

**Raw Data**

| Product Type | Sales QTY | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 4 | 1/9/21 |
| Orange | 3 | 6/9/21 |
| Banana | 2 | 10/9/21 |
| Apple | 6 | 14/9/21 |
| Orange | 6 | 20/9/21 |
| Apple | 5 | 29/9/21 |

The Criteria I want to match is in Column 1 (Product Type) of the summary table.

Basically, I then want to be able to end up with the ability to display the data either as **Totals**:

`$F$5 = 9`

for each line:  `SUBTOTAL($F$5,SalesQTY)`

**Summary Table**

| Product Type | Result (Sales Per Month) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 15 |
| Orange | 9 |
| Banana | 2 |

Or as **Averages**:

`$F$5 = 1`

for each line:  `SUBTOTAL($F$5,SalesQTY)`

| Product Type | Result (Average QTY per Sale) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 |
| Orange | 4.5 |
| Banana | 2 |

Or as a **Count**:

`$F$5 = 2`

for each line:  `SUBTOTAL($F$5,SalesQTY)`

| Product Type | Result (# Sales Transactions) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Banana | 1 |

Is there some way I can combine SUMIF and also SUBTOTAL but also be able to retain the ability to flick between average, sum and count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Used:

To avoid having to rework the many other tables in the sheet that rely on this field and also as some user open this file with older (non-365) versions of excel, I opted for a series of nested IF (CountIF, SumIF, AverageIF) statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula to create a dynamic summary table in excel 365. If you have any earlier version of excel, the formula would be different and rows would have to be manually added or removed. I'm assuming your table is called `Data_Table`.

```
=LET(
    Column_Product, Data_Table[Product Type],
    Column_QTY, Data_Table[Estimated],
    Column_Date, Data_Table[Date]

    Column_Key, Column_Product,
    Column_Filter1, Column_QTY,
    Column_Filter2, Column_Date,
    
    List_Filter1, UNIQUE(Column_Product),
    List_Filter2, 1,

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(Column_Key)),
    Array_BoolKey, (TRANSPOSE(Column_Key)=Categories)+0,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Column_Filter1,List_Filter1))),
    Mask2, TRANSPOSE(Column_Filter2>List_Filter2),

    Array_BoolMasked, Array_BoolKey*Mask1*Mask2,
    Masked_QTY, IFERROR(Array_BoolMasked*TRANSPOSE(Column_QTY),0),
    Masked_Date, IFERROR(Array_BoolMasked*TRANSPOSE(Column_Date),0),

    Array_Ones, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array_BoolMasked),1,1,0),

    Months, DATEDIF(MIN(Column_Date),MAX(Column_Date),"M"),

    Body_Count, MMULT(Array_BoolMasked, Array_Ones),
    Body_Sum_QTY, MMULT(Masked_FtModeled, Array_Ones),
    Body_Average_PerSale, Body_Sum_QTY/Body_Count,
    Body_Sum_QTY_PerMo, MMULT(Masked_FtModeled, Array_Ones)/Months,

    Total_Count, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Count_Lines),"-"),
    Total_QTY_PerMo, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Sum_QTY)/Months,"-"),
    Total_Average_PerSale, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Sum_QTY)/Total_Count,"-"),

    Array_Seq, {1,2,3,4,5},
    Array_Header, CHOOSE(Array_Seq, "Product Type", "Sales Per Month", "Average QTY per Sale", "# Sales Transactions"),
    Array_Body, CHOOSE(Array_Seq, Categories, Body_Sum_QTY_PerMo,  Body_Average_PerSale, Body_Count),
    Array_Total, CHOOSE(Array_Seq,  "Total", Total_QTY_PerMo, Total_Average_PerSale,  Total_Count),

    Range1,Array_Header,
    Range2,Array_Body,
    Range3,Array_Total,
    Rows1,ROWS(Range1), Rows2,ROWS(Range2), Rows3,ROWS(Range3), Cols1,COLUMNS(Range1),
    RowIndex, SEQUENCE(Rows1 + Rows2 + Rows3), ColIndex,SEQUENCE(1, Cols1),
    RangeTable,IF(
        RowIndex<=Rows1,
        INDEX(Range1,RowIndex,ColIndex),
        IF(RowIndex<=Rows1+Rows2,
            INDEX(Range2,RowIndex-Rows1,ColIndex),
            INDEX(Range3,RowIndex-Rows1-Rows2,ColIndex)
    )),

    Return, RangeTable,
    Return
)
```

I wrote this generically so you could add filters for only certain products, or minimum quantity, or a date range, or other criteria. Above, I set up the filter to pass everything.

Comment: Thanks for this - I will give it a go. Although some users open this file in other versions of Excel - will this mean they will have compatibility issues?

Comment: The formula will return `#NAME!` in earlier versions of excel.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Will have to look for alternatives. Thanks though, I will save this solution for when/ if we ever fully transition to 365

Comment: I ended up just doing a nested set of IFS so I could avoid by rework until we switch over. Thanks again